# Positioning subview with arbitrary anchoring point in superview

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I have hard times to figure out proper algorithm. I have a superview (green) and a subview (yellow). Having an arbitrary anchor point (just a choosen point, not to mix with layer's `anchor` property) in this subview (red) I have to place and to resize the subview in the way that this red point gets placed *in the center of the superview* and the subview gets resized *proportionally* if needed (if after moving its frame goes out of superview's bounds). No Auto Layout used. See picture what I want to get.

So basically I wrote a C++ test routine where a new proportional rectange is calculated "around" given new point (so this point gets center of this new rectangle), but I don not know what to do next to handle a point which is not in center of the subview. `Rect` is basically a struct with `x, y, width, height` members.

```
    Rect
    calculateRectInBounds(const Rect &boundingRect, const Rect &initialRect, const Point &translationPoint)
    {
        double boundsWidth = boundingRect.getWidth();
        double boundsHeight = boundingRect.getHeight();
        double distanceX, distanceY;
        Size sizeByWidth, sizeByHeight;

        // detect part where point is

        /*
         * UL | UR
         * ---C---
         * LL | LR
         */

        // -- upper left - check left & top borders

        if (translationPoint.x <= boundsWidth / 2 && translationPoint.y < boundsHeight / 2) {
            distanceX = translationPoint.x;
            distanceY = translationPoint.y;

            sizeByWidth = scaleSizeToWidth(initialRect.getSize(), distanceX);
            sizeByHeight = scaleSizeToHeight(initialRect.getSize(), distanceY);

            if (sizeByWidth.height > distanceY) {
                return {translationPoint.x - sizeByHeight.width,
                        0,
                        sizeByHeight.width * 2,
                        sizeByHeight.height * 2};
            }

            return {0,
                    translationPoint.y - sizeByWidth.height,
                    sizeByWidth.width * 2,
                    sizeByWidth.height * 2};
        }

        // -- upper right - check top & right borders

        if (translationPoint.x > boundsWidth / 2 && translationPoint.y <= boundsHeight / 2) {
            distanceX = boundsWidth - translationPoint.x;
            distanceY = translationPoint.y;

            sizeByWidth = scaleSizeToWidth(initialRect.getSize(), distanceX);
            sizeByHeight = scaleSizeToHeight(initialRect.getSize(), distanceY);

            if (sizeByWidth.height > distanceY) {
                return {translationPoint.x - sizeByHeight.width,
                        0,
                        sizeByHeight.width * 2,
                        sizeByHeight.height * 2};
            }

            return {translationPoint.x - sizeByWidth.width,
                    translationPoint.y - sizeByWidth.height,
                    sizeByWidth.width * 2,
                    sizeByWidth.height * 2};
        }

        // -- lower right - check right & bottom borders

        if (translationPoint.x >= boundsWidth / 2 && translationPoint.y > boundsHeight / 2) {
            distanceX = boundsWidth - translationPoint.x;
            distanceY = boundsHeight - translationPoint.y;

            sizeByWidth = scaleSizeToWidth(initialRect.getSize(), distanceX);
            sizeByHeight = scaleSizeToHeight(initialRect.getSize(), distanceY);

            if (sizeByWidth.height > distanceY) {
                return {translationPoint.x - sizeByHeight.width,
                        translationPoint.y - sizeByHeight.height,
                        sizeByHeight.width * 2,
                        sizeByHeight.height * 2};
            }

            return {translationPoint.x - sizeByWidth.width,
                    translationPoint.y - sizeByWidth.height,
                    sizeByWidth.width * 2,
                    sizeByWidth.height * 2};
        }

        // -- lower left - check bottom & left borders

        if (translationPoint.x < boundsWidth / 2 && translationPoint.y >= boundsHeight / 2) {
            distanceX = translationPoint.x;
            distanceY = boundsHeight - translationPoint.y;

            sizeByWidth = scaleSizeToWidth(initialRect.getSize(), distanceX);
            sizeByHeight = scaleSizeToHeight(initialRect.getSize(), distanceY);

            if (sizeByWidth.height > distanceY) {
                return {translationPoint.x - sizeByHeight.width,
                        translationPoint.y - sizeByHeight.height,
                        sizeByHeight.width * 2,
                        sizeByHeight.height * 2};
            }

            return {0,
                    translationPoint.y - sizeByWidth.height,
                    sizeByWidth.width * 2,
                    sizeByWidth.height * 2};
        }

        // -- center

        return initialRect;
    }

Size
scaleSizeToWidth(Size size, double newWidth)
{
    return {newWidth, (std::min(size.width, newWidth) / std::max(size.width, newWidth)) * size.height};
}

Size
scaleSizeToHeight(Size size, double newHeight)
{
    return {(std::min(size.height, newHeight) / std::max(size.height, newHeight)) * size.width, newHeight};
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Thanks to answer of @MBo correct routine

```
    Rect
    calculateRectInBounds(const Rect &boundingRect, const Rect &initialRect, const Point &anchorPoint)
    {
        auto lDist = anchorPoint.x - initialRect.getX();
        auto rDist = initialRect.getWidth() - lDist;
        auto tDist = anchorPoint.y - initialRect.getY();
        auto bDist = initialRect.getHeight() - tDist;

        auto lRatio = (lDist * 2) / boundingRect.getWidth();
        auto rRatio = (rDist * 2) / boundingRect.getWidth();
        auto tRatio = (tDist * 2) / boundingRect.getHeight();
        auto bRatio = (bDist * 2) / boundingRect.getHeight();

        auto scale = 1 / std::max({lRatio, rRatio, tRatio, bRatio});

        auto x = initialRect.getWidth() / 2 - lDist * scale + initialRect.getX();
        auto y = initialRect.getHeight() / 2 - tDist * scale + initialRect.getY();
        auto width = initialRect.getWidth() * scale;
        auto height = initialRect.getHeight() * scale;

        return {x, y, width, height};
    }
```

Comment: 1) move subview with redpoint to center of view 2) calculate vectors from red point to angles of subview 3) calculate intersections between extended lines {red_point, sub_view_angle} and borders of view 4) scale sub_view to a minimum of required extensions at point (3) using red point as anchor for scale. If I am not mistaken this algorithm should lead to what you want to achieve. It may need some minor tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get distances from red point to all edges of subview rect

```
RedX, YellowWidth-RedX, RedY, YellowHeight - RedY
```

and calculate 4 ratios with superview sizes

```
L = (2 * RedX) / GreenWidth
R = (2 * (YellowWidth-RedX)) / GreenWidth
T = (2 * RedY) / GreenHeight
B = (2 * (YellowHeight-RedY)) / GreenHeight
```

then find maximum of them

```
Mx = Max(L,R,T,B)
```

Now determine scale:

```
Scale = 1 / Mx
```

New subview coordinates:

```
X =  YellowWidth / 2  - (RedX * Scale)
Y =  YellowHeight / 2  - (RedY * Scale)
```